# Issue with .reduce() method to multiply or divide

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to use reduce to operate this calculator but I'm having some issues when I'm trying to multiply or divide the numbers. The result of the multiplication is 0 and the result of the division is Infinity.
I'm getting always a 0 in the array and I tried to use the method .pop() to delete that 0 but is not working. Hope some one can help me.

Thank you!

```js
let resultadosObtenidos = [];
let numerosIntroducidos = [];

function iniciamosCalculadoraPRO() {
  const introducirNum = () => {
    let datosObtenidos = [];
    let datos;
    do {
      datos = Number(prompt('Introduce un número.'));
      if (isNaN(datos)) {
        alert('Debes introducir solo números NO letras.');
        return introducirNum();
      } else {
        datosObtenidos.push(datos);
      }
    }
    while (datos !== 0)
    return datosObtenidos
  }
  numerosIntroducidos = introducirNum();

  const operacionesCalculadora = () => {
    let operaciones = [];
    if (numerosIntroducidos.length > 1) {
      const suma = numerosIntroducidos.reduce((valorInicial, segundoValor) => valorInicial + segundoValor);
      const resta = numerosIntroducidos.reduce((valorInicial, segundoValor) => valorInicial - segundoValor);
      const multiplicacion = numerosIntroducidos.reduce((valorInicial, segundoValor) => valorInicial * segundoValor);
      const division = numerosIntroducidos.reduce((valorInicial, segundoValor) => valorInicial / segundoValor);



      operaciones.push('La suma es: ' + suma + ' La resta es: ' + resta + ' La multiplicación es: ' + multiplicacion + ' La división es: ' + division);
      return operaciones;
    }
  }
  resultadosObtenidos = operacionesCalculadora();



  const mostramosResultadosOperaciones = () => {
    if (numerosIntroducidos.length > 2) {
      alert("Los resultados son: " + resultadosObtenidos);
    }
  }
  mostramosResultadosOperaciones();


  const repetimosProceso = () => {
    if (confirm("Quieres volver hacer calculos?")) {
      return iniciamosCalculadoraPRO();
    } else {
      alert("Gracias por usar nuestra calculadora PRO.");
    }
  }
  repetimosProceso();
}
iniciamosCalculadoraPRO();
```

I want to understand how to delete that 0 of the array and finally get my correct results in the calculator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `0` to end the list of inputs, but you're also pushing that onto the `datosObtenidos`  array. When you multiply by 0, you get 0. When you divide by 0, you get infinity.

The value that you're using to terminate the input shouldn't be pushed onto the array.

Also, you shouldn't call `introducirNum()` recursively when you get an invalid input, since that will discard all the previous inputs. Use a nested loop for invalid inputs.

```js
let resultadosObtenidos = [];
let numerosIntroducidos = [];

function iniciamosCalculadoraPRO() {
  const introducirNum = () => {
    let datosObtenidos = [];
    let datos;
    while (true) {
      while (true) {
        datos = Number(prompt('Introduce un número.'));
        if (isNaN(datos)) {
          alert('Debes introducir solo números NO letras.');
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (datos == 0) {
        break;
      } else {
        datosObtenidos.push(datos);
      }
    }
    return datosObtenidos
  }
  numerosIntroducidos = introducirNum();

  const operacionesCalculadora = () => {
    let operaciones = [];
    if (numerosIntroducidos.length > 1) {
      const suma = numerosIntroducidos.reduce((valorInicial, segundoValor) => valorInicial + segundoValor);
      const resta = numerosIntroducidos.reduce((valorInicial, segundoValor) => valorInicial - segundoValor);
      const multiplicacion = numerosIntroducidos.reduce((valorInicial, segundoValor) => valorInicial * segundoValor);
      const division = numerosIntroducidos.reduce((valorInicial, segundoValor) => valorInicial / segundoValor);



      operaciones.push('La suma es: ' + suma + ' La resta es: ' + resta + ' La multiplicación es: ' + multiplicacion + ' La división es: ' + division);
      return operaciones;
    }
  }
  resultadosObtenidos = operacionesCalculadora();



  const mostramosResultadosOperaciones = () => {
    if (numerosIntroducidos.length > 2) {
      alert("Los resultados son: " + resultadosObtenidos);
    }
  }
  mostramosResultadosOperaciones();


  const repetimosProceso = () => {
    if (confirm("Quieres volver hacer calculos?")) {
      return iniciamosCalculadoraPRO();
    } else {
      alert("Gracias por usar nuestra calculadora PRO.");
    }
  }
  repetimosProceso();
}
iniciamosCalculadoraPRO();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Okay, I understand the issue with that 0 but with that solution the calculator is not working properly. It seems that now it is not calculating and it is always asking if I want to introduce new numbers. I really don't know how to fix this.

Comment: How many numbers did you give? `if (numerosIntroducidos.length > 2)` only shows the result if you enter 3 or more numbers, and this doesn't include the `0`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I get it! this last one issue it was so silly. Thank you again!

Comment: I was confused by that as well.